# do news aggregators Parse on Client or Server side?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, rss, feedly

Applications like Pulse, Feedly, and various other news aggregators show structured data like "Headline", "Subject", "source", "time of publishing". etc.

I imagine some of this information is obtained from RSS feeds from various websites. My question is, do these Apps and website parse the information on the server side and send the structured information to phone/website... or... do they place the parser in the website/App and just send the raw link? What are the pros and cons of either method?

still learning!!

Answer (score 1):

They all (that I know of!) do it on the server side. First, for web based apps, it's actually not possible due to CORS reasons to fetch feeds on another domain than the one of the reader.
Then, it also allows them to cache things efficiently and even do things like PubSubHubbub subscriptions.